# Sencha Touch 2.1 infinite loading screen if UserAgent is set to iOS

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

my local preview of my first sencha touch app ('raw' / build) works just fine with no errors and no warnings. Whenever i set the UserAgent to iOS, i'll get an infinite loading screen (3 blinking dots) also with no errors and no warnings.

any suggestions on how i can fix this?

thank you in advance

Comment: It would be good so see some code like the index.html, app.js and what relative to the app start-up

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used the wrong cordova.js. This caused alot of confusion because no errormessage was printed out. We fixed it by replacing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the browser console (in Chrome: right click, Inspect element, Console tab) and look for the error message.